# adding comma to every line in a file

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble placing "," after the end of each line using the following code. Any thoughts, please ?

```
$inputFile = Get-Content "C:\PowerShell Automation\data.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\PowerShell Automation\dataoutput.txt"

    foreach($Obj in $inputFile)
    {       
    $begin = ""
    $end = ","
    $collate = $begin + $Obj + $end

    Set-Content -path $outputFile -value $collate
    }
```

Sample data in file is as below :

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
1533080972
1533080971
https://www.tamu.edu/
```

Comment: How would you describe the trouble? Do you get no output or the wrong output? If the latter, then editing your question to show a small sample of input data, actual output, and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just get last line as output to the file. The output file only has the following content : 
https://www.tamu.edu,

Comment: Use `Out-File` with the `-Append` parameter instead. `Set-Content` is replacing the entire content of the specified file each time it is called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overwrite the file with every iteration of your `foreach`-loop. Place `Set-Content` outside of the loop, as well as the `$collate` variable.

```
$inputFile = Get-Content "C:\PowerShell Automation\data.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\PowerShell Automation\dataoutput.txt"

$collate = foreach($Obj in $inputFile) {       
    $begin = ""
    $end = ","
    $begin + $Obj + $end

    }

Set-Content -path $outputFile -value $collate
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with a one-liner:

```
gc data.txt | %{$_ -replace '$',','} | out-file dataoutput.txt
```

Get the content of the file, go through line by line, replace the end of the line with a comma, and output to the new file.

Comment: You could also do `(gc data.txt) -replace '$', ','`.